# any way to know the latest action that was dispatched in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am working on a react-with-redux application I am working with the library redux-undo and as the capability of the library goes, it listens to a list of actions and reverts to the previous state when the undo happens.

Scenario: I have a page where a list item will be created/deleted and a API call is made whenever these actions happen. The user can undo both the create and delete operations.

I would like to know if there is any way to know the latest action that has been dispatched.

For example: If the user creates a list item and clicks undo, I would like to know that the latest action that was dispatched was create, so that I can revert the create(delete the list item by making an API call).

Like wise, If the user deleted an list item I would like to know that the latest action that was dispatched was delete, so that I can revert the delete(create the list item again by making an API call, fetching the details from past shape of state and sending the details of the deleted list item)

Please let m know if there is any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `store.subscribe`, as stated [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/580#issuecomment-133188511):

> The easiest way is to have a reducer that remembers just the last action:

```
function lastAction(state = null, action) {
  return action;
}
```

> Then you can use store.getState().lastAction, assuming you did
>   something like

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  someReducer,
  someOtherReducer,
  lastAction // <-- use it!
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState().lastAction);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It works, and I get the lastAction in the format:{action:###, payload:###}. The action that I want is store.getState().lastAction.payload.   Is there anyway I can get the payload associated with that action?

Comment: The payload will be in the `lastAction` e.g:

if you do `dispatch({type: 'DO_ACTION', payload: 123})`
 
then you should find the payload normally `store.getState().lastAction.payload` -> `123`

Answer (score 2):

You would need to find an alternative storage space to store your latest action that is unaffected by `redux-undo` but also global so you can access it anywhere you need.

I recommend a `local storage` solution.

In your reducer, you can add a statement to set which was the latest dispatched action into browser storage:

```
...
case CREATE: {
  localStorage.setItem("latestAction", "CREATE");
  return someNewState;
}
case DELETE: {
  localStorage.setItem("latestAction", "DELETE");
  return someNewState;
}
...
```

Then when you want to get that value from anywhere in code:

```
localStorage.getItem("latestAction");
```